# AWS Cloudwatch logs status shows running but logs are not available in AWS console

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

I am new to aws and I have to publish the application service logs to cloud watch. I tried the steps mentioned in AWS documentation and its working. I configured the same steps via jenkins pipeline. Here i am facing an issue. Logs are not getting published i.e. I could not see the logs from AWS console. I logged on to the ec2 instance and check the cloudwatch service status and it shows

```
{
  "status": "running",
  "starttime": "2021-03-25T07:40:21+0000",
  "configstatus": "configured",
  "cwoc_status": "stopped",
  "cwoc_starttime": "",
  "cwoc_configstatus": "not configured",
  "version": "1.247347.3b250378"
}
```

Don't understand what is wrong here :(.

Any help would be helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does your IAM role bound to EC2 have permission to write to CloudWatch?

Comment: Yes IAM role bound to EC2 have permission to write to CloudWatch

Comment: can you share more information which doc you followed for setting. I followed this [Quick Start: Install and Configure the CloudWatch Logs Agent on a Running EC2 Linux Instance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/QuickStartEC2Instance.html) and it worked without any trouble.

Comment: @samtoddler I have followed the steps mentioned here [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/install-CloudWatch-Agent-commandline-fleet.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I followed the link mentioned by you [Installing and Running the CloudWatch Agent on Your Servers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/install-CloudWatch-Agent-commandline-fleet.html).

Below is my configuration for pushing the logs and few other metrics, which is generated by this command

[Run the CloudWatch Agent Configuration Wizard](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/create-cloudwatch-agent-configuration-file-wizard.html#cloudwatch-agent-running-wizard)

```sh
sudo /opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/bin/amazon-cloudwatch-agent-config-wizard
```

```json
{
        "agent": {
                "metrics_collection_interval": 60,
                "run_as_user": "root"
        },
        "logs": {
                "logs_collected": {
                        "files": {
                                "collect_list": [
                                        {
                                                "file_path": "/var/log/messages",
                                                "log_group_name": "messages",
                                                "log_stream_name": "{instance_id}"
                                        }
                                ]
                        }
                }
        },
        "metrics": {
... # metrics configuration here
        }
}
```

Started the client as described in the doc

```sh
/opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/bin/amazon-cloudwatch-agent-ctl -a \
fetch-config -m ec2 -s -c file:///opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/bin/config.json
```

[Start the CloudWatch Agent Using the Command Line](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/create-cloudwatch-agent-configuration-file-wizard.html#cloudwatch-agent-running-wizard)

```sh
# /opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/bin/amazon-cloudwatch-agent-ctl -a status
{
  "status": "running",
  "starttime": "2021-03-26T11:46:14+0000",
  "version": "1.247345.35"
}
```

[image]

You can look for troubles inside the logs directory if there are any

```
[root@ip-xx amazon-cloudwatch-agent]# ls
amazon-cloudwatch-agent.log  configuration-validation.log  state
[root@ip-xx amazon-cloudwatch-agent]# pwd
/var/log/amazon/amazon-cloudwatch-agent
```

On the side note if I just want to push the logs to cloudwatch, I would use this one

[Quick Start: Install and Configure the CloudWatch Logs Agent on a Running EC2 Linux Instance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/QuickStartEC2Instance.html)

Comment: My configuration and steps are same. The only difference that I could see is the user. "run_as_user": "cwagent"

Comment: can this be the reason??

Comment: @Priyanka yes if the user `cwagent` doesnt has t he permissions to read the logs, which you are trying to push, then this creates the trouble. [Running the CloudWatch Agent as a Different User](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/CloudWatch-Agent-common-scenarios.html#CloudWatch-Agent-run-as-user). Try chaning the user to `root`. Should work if not you can follow the guide linked to run the agent as different user.

Comment: that was the issue.. run_as_user : cwagent was not having permissions. Changed it to the root.. and now its working fine.. Thanks :)